# Using yacc and lex, I got a compile error : usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ly

Tags: linux, gcc, compilation, yacc, lex

I'm reading compiler book that Jhon R. Levine's *lex and yacc*

Even after following the first example in Chapter 3, the first example is as follows.

```
/*parser.y*/

%token NAME NUMBER

%%

statement: NAME '=' expression
 | expression { printf("= %d\n", $1); }
 ;
 expression: expression '+' NUMBER { $$ = $1 + $3; }
 | expression '-' NUMBER { $$ = $1 - $3; }
 | NUMBER { $$ = $1; }
 ;
```

```
/*parser.l*/

%{
#include "y.tab.h"
extern int yylval;
%}

%%

[0-9]+ { yylval = atoi(yytext); return NUMBER; }
[ \t] ; /* ignore whitespace */
\n return 0; /* logical EOF */
.   {yyerror("error!! %c\n",*yytext);}
%%
```

And when I ran these two files on the terminal, the following error came out while compiling the two files.

```
$ yacc -d parser.y
$ lex parser.l 
$ cc -o parser y.tab.c lex.yy.c -ly -ll
```

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ly
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What should I do?
Please help me.

Comment: What OS are you using? How did  you install "yacc"?

Comment: If using a Debian/Ubuntu based distro, you might need to install the `libbison-dev` package.

Comment: ubuntu terminal app on Windows. thanks i'm trying that

Comment: Using flex and  bison

Comment: Wow it's done !! Thank you